# Weird printf output in C (unknown characters & signs)

Tags: c, printf, output

I just started getting a weird `printf` output, has anyone ever seen this? Any idea what it could be caused by?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP7n3.jpg

**Edit**

Here's the code. I'm new to c so if anything (even if it's not causing the error) looks wrong or uncommon please tell me.

```
       printf(f2,"%8.31f\t%8.31f\n",x[0],x[2]);
       fprintf(f2,"%8.31f\t%8.31f\n",x[1],x[2]);
```

Comment: You'll have to post the code.

Comment: post your code then only we can say.

Comment: let's say I'm browsing with images disable. Now what?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must __describe the specific problem__ — and __include valid code__ to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://SSCCE.org) for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you write:

```
if (x[0]*oldx<0)
{
   printf(f2,"%8.31f\t%8.31f\n",x[0],x[2]);
   fprintf(f2,"%8.31f\t%8.31f\n",x[1],x[2]);
}
```

where `f2` is a pointer to `FILE`, which shall not be passed as the first parameter of `printf`. Just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem is on lines 96-97:

```
   printf(f2,"%8.31f\t%8.31f\n",x[0],x[2]);
   fprintf(f2,"%8.31f\t%8.31f\n",x[1],x[2]);
```

The first line should call `fprintf`, not `printf`.

Any compiler should give you at least a warning for calling `printf` with a `FILE*` as the first argument. Did you see such a warning? If so, why did you ignore it?

Compiling with additional warnings enabled should show you a number of other problems. Fix those before doing anything else.